# How to make parse object to json using retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

with the next problem, when trying to consume a webservice, then message and presentation;

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

I'm not sure how to make a scenario, I've already got data from a webservice, but when it's not a simple array.

I have tried many alternatives, but without success.

**response api**

```
  {
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://url.com/service?page=1"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://url.com/service"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://url.com/service?page=1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nome": "teste",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://url.com/service/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nome": "teste 2",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://url.com/service/2"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "page_count": 1,
    "page_size": 25,
    "total_items": 2,
    "page": 1
}
```

**Client**

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://url.com/";


    private static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static ApiInterface getApiService() {
        return getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

}
```

**Interface**

```
/**
 * Class ApiInterface
 */
public interface ApiInterface
{

    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/service")
    Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>> getData();


}
```

**Service**

```
public class Service{

    @SerializedName("data")
    private ArrayList<ServiceData> service = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Service Data**

```
public class ServiceData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;


    public ServiceData(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
 final Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>> service = apiService.getService();
        service.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ServiceData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>> call, Response<ArrayList<ServiceData>> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + t);

            }
        });
```

Comment: your response is the whole JSON, whereas the model you have created is only for the "_embedded.data" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right path but the response is the whole json and not  only the *data* part you want.

I would create the ResponseApi class:

```
public class ResponseApi {
    @SerializedName("_embedded")
    private Service embedded;
}
```

And change on ApiInterface:

```
Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>> getData();
```

To:

```
Call<ResponseApi> getData();
```

Also in your activity replace all *ArrayList<ServiceData>* with *ResponseApi*.

With only this changes your code should work. And then you'll need to add getters in ResponseApi and Service to access the saved data.

---

**UPDATE** adding some getters:

We need the possibility to get the ArrayList of ServiceData of services:

```
public class Service {
    // Your current code

    public List<ServiceData> getServices() {
        return service;
    }
}
```

And also we could create a getter in ResponseApi to get embedded *getEmbedded* (I'll add the code as info only) but since we only want the services we could create a getter to the list of services *getEmbededServices* and use this last method.

```
public class ResponseApi {
    // Your current code

    public Service getEmbedded() { // Not used, only shown as info
        return embedded;
    }

    public List<ServiceData> getEmbeddedServices() {
        return embedded.getServices();
    }
}
```

This way, when you'll receive a ResponseApi object in the onResponse method you can call its getEmbeddedServices to get the List of ServiceData and then you can loop through them to get the ids:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseApi> call, Response<ResponseApi> response) {
    Log.d(TAG, "services: " + response.getEmbeddedServices());
    // Here you can loop the response.getEmbeddedServices() which is a List of ServiceData and get each of the ids. Ex:
    for (ServiceData serviceData : response.getEmbeddedServices()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "service Id: " + serviceData.getId());
        // Here you have access to the ids and can do whatever you need with them.
    }
}
```

---

By the way, **only as a suggestion**, I would rename (with refactor in Android Studio) this *service* var (in *Service* class):

```
private ArrayList<ServiceData> service = new ArrayList<>();
```

To *servicesList*:

```
private ArrayList<ServiceData> servicesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And maybe also refactor the *Service* class to *ServicesList* class.

It's going to work either you rename them or not but, in my opinion, the code is more readable this way.

Comment: Your response was human and perfect, thank you, I'm getting my array, a single question, in this scenario my response data will no longer be used?
And if I just want to get the id, how could it be?

I have tried in some ways to create my attributes using the service, and creating the getters, but I can not access them.

Comment: Thanks, don't worry, I've just added an update to explain a way of accessing the needed data by adding some getters. I've not run it but it should work.

Comment: With minor modifications I got the result that I expected, I have no words to thank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Your Parsing mapping has issues try below Model

ServiceData.java

```
public class ServiceData {

@SerializedName("_links")
@Expose
private Links links;
@SerializedName("_embedded")
@Expose
private Embedded embedded;
@SerializedName("page_count")
@Expose
private Integer pageCount;
@SerializedName("page_size")
@Expose
private Integer pageSize;
@SerializedName("total_items")
@Expose
private Integer totalItems;
@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private Integer page;

public Links getLinks() {
return links;
}

public void setLinks(Links links) {
this.links = links;
}

public Embedded getEmbedded() {
return embedded;
}

public void setEmbedded(Embedded embedded) {
this.embedded = embedded;
}

public Integer getPageCount() {
return pageCount;
}

public void setPageCount(Integer pageCount) {
this.pageCount = pageCount;
}

public Integer getPageSize() {
return pageSize;
}

public void setPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

public Integer getTotalItems() {
return totalItems;
}

public void setTotalItems(Integer totalItems) {
this.totalItems = totalItems;
}

public Integer getPage() {
return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
this.page = page;
}

}
```

Self_.java

```
    public class Self_ {

    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;

    public String getHref() {
    return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
    }

    }
```

Self.java

```
    public class Self {

    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;

    public String getHref() {
    return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
    }

    }
```

Links_.java

```
    public class Links_ {

    @SerializedName("self")
    @Expose
    private Self_ self;

    public Self_ getSelf() {
    return self;
    }

    public void setSelf(Self_ self) {
    this.self = self;
    }

    }
```

Links.java

```
    public class Links {

    @SerializedName("self")
    @Expose
    private Self self;
    @SerializedName("first")
    @Expose
    private First first;
    @SerializedName("last")
    @Expose
    private Last last;

    public Self getSelf() {
    return self;
    }

    public void setSelf(Self self) {
    this.self = self;
    }

    public First getFirst() {
    return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(First first) {
    this.first = first;
    }

    public Last getLast() {
    return last;
    }

    public void setLast(Last last) {
    this.last = last;
    }
    }
```

Last.java

```
    public class Last {

    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;

    public String getHref() {
    return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
    }

    }
```

First.java

```
    public class First {

    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose
    private String href;

    public String getHref() {
    return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
    }

    }
```

Embedded.java

```
    public class Embedded {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;

    public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    }
```

Datum.java

```
    public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("nome")
    @Expose
    private String nome;
    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    private Links_ links;

    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
    return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Links_ getLinks() {
    return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Links_ links) {
    this.links = links;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ArrayList from every where and direct use ServiceData

**Interface**

```
/**
 * Class ApiInterface
 */
public interface ApiInterface
{

    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/service")
    Call<ServiceData> getData();


}
```

**Service Data**

```
public class ServiceData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;


    public ServiceData(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
 final Call<ServiceData> service = apiService.getService();
        service.enqueue(new Callback<ServiceData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServiceData> call, Response<ServiceData> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServiceData> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + t);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You call and waiting for List. `Call<ArrayList<ServiceData>>`
But in the response, you have an object.

`[...]` - is array (list)
`{...}` - is object

You need to create classes for all parameters properly.

Just try to look at this service (or similar):
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Or Android Studio (IDEA) also has a plugin (GsonFormat) for converting JSON.